# In the phrase "man enough", is man an adjective?

Tags: grammar, idioms

I do realize that the phrase *"to be man enough"* is an idiom. But I wonder what is the grammatical/syntactic role that *man* plays in it. Is it an uncountable noun? An adjective? An adverb? Or perhaps because the phrase is an idiom, the question makes no sense?

Comment: It's a *noun **used** as an adjective*, as in such usages as *"He never asks for directions. It's a man thing"*. In your context you could reasonably substitute the explicitly adjectival form ***manly***.

Comment: Good question! Firstly, M-W's sense (2) of _man_ is relevant: man noun 
:(1) an adult male human being

:(2) a man or boy who shows the qualities (such as strength and courage) that men are traditionally supposed to have // Secondly, while the first sense is classifying (given a decision on when the adolescent  – man transition occurs), the second is gradeable (consider the related adjective 'manly'). This doesn't really answer your question, though. I'd treat 'X enough'  – where X appears to be a noun as a snowclone (a productive idiom)  – modelled on 'adj enough'.

Comment: It’s an attributive noun, a noun adjunct. In other words, it is one noun used to modify another. Although all adjectives modify nouns, not all things that modify nouns are adjectives. This is very common error of logic.

Comment: @tchrist: And which noun does man modify here?

Comment: Note that the phrase alludes to "be a man", as in *If you can fill the unforgiving minute / With sixty seconds’ worth of distance run, /
Yours is the Earth and everything that’s in it, / And—which is more—you’ll be a Man, my son!* -- Rudyard Kipling's *If*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an alternative sentence:

*He is sufficiently manly to achieve his goals.*

Here *manly* is an adjective and *sufficiently manly* is an adjectival phrase.  In your sentence, *man enough*  is a colloquial substitute..........so it is also adjectival.  
 
Because of its colloquial nature, I would only catagorize the phrase and not break it down further.

Comment: To answer the question, you have to specify a part of speech or say that that would be unprofitable here.

Comment: @Edwin: But this answer explicitly *says* OP's usage is ***adjectival*** (for which I'm upvoting).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree with you......and have expanded my answer.

Comment: @FF Saying " 'man enough' is adjectival in sentence A" is very different from saying " 'man' is an adjective in sentence A". Attributive nouns are obviously adjectival (= 'acting to modify a noun' or 'doing the job of an adjective'). 'Adjectivals' include more than just adjectives; though the adjective 'adjectival' is polysemous, its main sense is usually taken as being 'acting as (ie doing the job of) an adjective'.

Answer (score 5):

*Man* is a **noun** in constructions such as 'to be man enough'.

To be more specific, *man* is a predicate noun, or a noun used in the predicate of a sentence. The *Oxford English Dictionary* (OED), under the definition of *enough*, gives an example of this exact phrase, from, coincidentally, another dictionary, the *New English Dictionary (N.E.D.)*.

> 1891 *N.E.D.* He was not **man enough** to confess the truth.

The description in the OED of *enough* in this usage is

> quasi-adjective, qualifying a **noun** used as a predicate

Note the term *quasi-adjective* describes *enough*, not *man*. Other OED examples that fall under this same entry for *enough* are

> 1711 The Butler has been **Fool enough** to be seduced by them.

and

> 1878  Looking at a spot into which she was not **climber enough** to venture.

*Fool* and *climber* are nouns.

In additon, the first definition of *enough* in the OED says:

> 1. in concord with **noun**, expressed or implied:

and as examples for *with **noun** in singular* it gives uses from Old English (prior to ~1100) through Middle English to Modern English, and they include

> 1518 With payne and **trauayle anough**, we made toward the Cowrte. (With pain and **travail enough**, we made toward the Court--my updating of this sentence)
>
> approx1616  There's **wood enough** within. (Shakespeare, *The Tempest*)
>
> 1766 He had not **resolution enough** to give any man pain by a denial.
>
> 1816  That thought is **happiness Enough** for me.

etc.

Webster's [1828 Dictionary](http://1828.mshaffer.com/d/word/enough) notes that

> This word, in vulgar [common] language, is sometimes placed before its **noun**, like most other adjectives. But in elegant discourse or composition, it always follows the **noun**, to which it refers; as, bread enough; money enough.

---

Edited to add:

Another modifier that goes after the **noun** is *alive*. And here is [an example](https://books.google.com/books?id=C7nIjct3qcsC&pg=PA195&dq=%22I%20am%20man%22%20-enough&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWgZKQqKDKAhUGgj4KHQG3AAUQ6AEIOzAG#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> As for the scientist, he has absolutely no use for me so long as I am **man alive**.

Comment: It appears we are more commonly common than once we were.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of phrasing it is, "He is enough of a man." Then "enough" is an adjective, but "man" is something of a "qualifier," even though it is technically a noun. That may be where the confusion is coming from.

Comment: +1 I agree with that. Man is a noun. English often drops words which are easily understood. Man enough is shorthand for "enough of a man".